# New method with RequestMapping annotation returns 404

Tags: eclipse, spring-mvc, tomcat7, request-mapping

I have a new method in a controller class :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getExample", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody String getExample(final HttpServletRequest request,
            final HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
...
```

But it returns 404 when I call for e.g. `localhost:8081/App/api/getExample?param=1`

I am using Apache Tomcat 7.  I m using Eclipse and I have "Build automatically" turned on. It seems that the server is not picking up the changes. Any suggestions please?

Comment: Are you using the GET method? What does the server log say for this request?

Comment: Yes I m using GET method and I see 127.0.0.1 - - [22/Sep/2019:08:01:17 +0530] "GET /App/api/getExample?param=1 HTTP/1.1" 404 1013

Comment: Hmm, that's not quite the URL in your original question. Which one is correct?

Comment: Updated the question, it has an `api` that I missed before

Comment: In the tomcat Catalina logs do you see if /getExample uri is getting printed? if yes then your app was deployed on the server correctly. Now other setting needs to be checked is context root in your web.xml and what is the context root in the tomcat server when your was deployed.

Comment: @animeshk I do see the /getExample in Catalina logs, how do i see if context root in tomcat is right?

Comment: default context root is your application war name and you can change as follows...In your project's Properties, choose Web Project Settings.
Change Context root to whatever you want....also when you right click on your server in eclipse you can other configurations